# Ping not working on Linux with Hostname, How to fix this using the Azure approach?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, vmware, azure

When I install a linux VM, say Ubuntu, on AWS/on-premise VMWare or virtualbox, anywhere, I cannot ping my machine with another machine directly with hostname, I can do only with IPAddress.

No matter whether I installed wins or any other package, the issue persists.

It is working only with manual entries in hosts file.

But, if I install a Linux VM on Azure, it is able to ping another linux machine directly.

So, can anyone please how it is working with Azure, so that I can implement the same with other infrastructure also.

See some configuration on my azure machine:

```
uday@linux2:~$ uday@linux2:~$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files


uday@linux2:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

And, adding entries in hosts file is not an option suitable for this as Azure VMs for reference created, doesn't have any hosts file entries.
And, my infrastructure which we are planning to implement will be having more than 1000 linux machines, so not suitable to add 1000*1000 machine entries.

### This is the resolv.conf content:

```
uday@linux1:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search oank4c5w4pluni24escinpevlb.bx.internal.cloudapp.net
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure simply uses DNS. Each VM gets its own subdomain, for example my new VM named "test" is actually known as `test.bgi0vih2qcgezm5pktjeqarz2g.ax.internal.cloudapp.net` in Azure's internal DNS service. (Their VM creation system automatically adds and deletes DNS entries as needed.)

You can see this full name by running `hostname -f`, or by combining the output with `hostname` with the "search" line found in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

DNS is the most general solution for other VM hosting types, and the only scalable protocol if you have thousands of VMs. Some "cloud" providers already support it, in others you might be able to script the automatic updates (e.g. if your infra domain is hosted using BIND 9, then updates can be submitted via `nsupdate`).

Meanwhile, NBNS (which is used by the "wins" module) is probably your worst option. It is part of the old NetBIOS protocol; it uses IP "local broadcast" messages which might not work on many cloud providers, and on Windows even relies on SMBv1 support being present.

mDNS (provided by Avahi) and LLMNR (provided by systemd-resolved) are somewhat more modern and lightweight protocols, but they still share a few of the same problems that NBNS had: they use IP broadcasts, they only work within a single subnet, and they probably won't scale beyond a few hundred systems.

Comment: I have edited question with resolv.conf content also, can you see that once.
How to keep a similar environment in my test virtualbox VM

Comment: Yes, it doesn't change the answer in any way. I already tested using my own VM on Azure.

Comment: Yeah, I understood, can you please suggest how to setup this dns environment here in test machines.

Comment: I tried this option, but not working. https://devopsdiaryblog.wordpress.com/2017/11/06/resolve-ping-issue-with-hostname-linux/

Comment: That article has nothing to do with DNS. Those instructions install NetBIOS NBNS name lookup instead. (And they don't install the server, just the client. Samba's `nmbd` is the NetBIOS server.)

Comment: we have a windows dns server in the network and a dhcp server through which IP addresses are getting picked. Windows machines are able to pick directly the DNS settings, can we integrate with that as a solution or a different approach is there? Please guide me, I am new to linux environment.

Comment: Do you use "dynamic updates" in Windows DNS? If so, the same kind of updates can be sent using `nsupdate` on Linux, although you'll need to make your own script to automate it.